# how to show tamil and english characters in jcombobox - java

Tags: java, unicode

i read value from database and the values are

```
AD       விபத்துகள் - ACCIDENTS
AG       போராட்டம் - AGITATIONS
CM       வணிகம்& தொழில்கள் - COMMERCE & INDUSTRY
CN       சினிமா & தொலைக்காட்சி- CINEMA & TELEVISION
CR       குற்றங்கள் & நீதிமன்றங்கள் - CRIME & JUSTICE
ED       கல்வி -  EDUCATION
```

I need to set this to jcombobox. i used

```
 jcombobox.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

But it shows tamilfont correctly but english as boxbox(?????). Any idea plz suggest

Comment: basically it is char-encoding issue, you need to make all encoding to UTF-8 (from your java source, database connection, and any place where it gets encoded

Comment: Am using ut-8 character encoding during the database connection itself

Comment: then may be jvm doesn't have UTF 8 by default, try setting system property `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Arial Unicode MS" font instead of latha. It will solve your problem

```
 jcombobox.setFont(new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: This solved my problem but here space after shortcode is not coming. But anyway it is okay for me.